# Вопрос по коду с++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь разобраться с кодом (переводит число из 10 системы в любую).

```
char int_symbol(int in) {
    char out[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
        'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    return out[in];
}


void ten_base(int in, int base) {
    if (in<base) {
        cout << int_symbol(in);
        return;
    }
    ten_base(in / base, base);
    cout << int_symbol(in%base);
}
```

in - число.
base - система счисления.
Понимаю, что в out написаны допустимые символы, но как определяет, например, что A=10 в 16 системе счисления?

Comment: if (in<base) {    cout << int_symbol(in); ... что возвращает сивол ՛A',  когда in == 10

Comment: Ощущение, что либо вопрос задан неверно, либо ответ дан не тот... Просто для систем счисления с основанием более 10 принято считать, что после цифр идут буквы. Ну, а конкретно у вас - `'A'` - это 10-й символ в массиве `out` (считая с 0, понятно). Я бы все же рекомендовал вам уточнить свой вопрос - вам непонятен сам алгоритм (вряд ли, по коду этого не скажешь) или почему именно `A` для 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну все довольно просто. Написать было можно и без дублирования некоторого кода, но этот алгоритм таков:

1. Мы берем некоторое число в десятичной системе счисления и передаем его в функцию `ten_base`, дополнительно передав основание системы, в которой нужно вывести число.
2. Проверяем, больше ли наше число нужного основания. Если меньше, то значит остался последний разряд - выводим его и прерываем рекурсию.
3. Если число не меньше основания, то запускаем рекурсию с `in / base` - т.е. убрав младший разряд.
4. Выводим этот самый младший разряд - `in % base` - остаток от деления числа на основание и будет младшим разрядом. Кстати, это число будет лежать в интервале `[0; 15]` для основания `16`, и логично, что передав его в функцию `int_symbol` мы получим соответствующую цифру или букву.

Давайте теперь разберем на примере, как это работает. Возьмем число `154` и посмотрим, как оно выглядит с основанием `16`.

1. Отправляем его в `ten_base` - `ten_base(154, 16)`. Проверяем. Оно явно больше основания, идем дальше.
2. Теперь вызываем `ten_base` с параметрами `(154 / 16, 16)` - т.е. `(9, 16)`.
3. Делаем проверку. Ага, `9 < 16`. Выводим `int_symbol(9)` (что будет равно девятке же) и возвращаемся. Вывод сейчас выглядит так:

   ```
   9
   ```
4. Вышли из `ten_base(9, 16)`, т.е. из вызова этой функции в пункте 2. Далее выводим `int_symbol(154 % 16)`, т.е. `int_symbol(10)`. `int_symbol` тут вернет нам `A`, и вывод будет выглядеть так:

   ```
   9A
   ```

Теперь возвращаемся из рекурсии. Все готово.

Немного сложно понять алгоритм, так как рекурсивный вызов идет до вывода разряда:

```
ten_base(in / base, base);
cout << int_symbol(in%base);
```

Это сделано для того, чтобы разряды выводились не от младшего к старшему, а наоборот, ведь в вывод они записываются слева направо. Если вы поменяете эти две строки местами, то будет слегка понятнее:

1. Выводим младший разряд числа по какому-то основанию.
2. Убираем младший разряд из числа (как будто убираем нижний кубик башенки) и повторяем процедуру.

Однако в таком случае разряды будут записаны в обратном порядке.

Не знаю, надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

**UPD** В самом начале я написал, что можно избежать дублирования. Будем запускать рекурсию лишь тогда, когда число не меньше основания:

```
void ten_base(int in, int base) {
    if (in >= base) {
        ten_base(in / base, base);
    }

    cout << int_symbol(in % base);
}
```

Таким образом, в данном коде больше нет дублирования `cout << int_symbol(in % base)`, а принцип работы остается тем же.

Comment: _`if (in == 0) {`_ - после такого изменения для нуля начнёт выводиться пустая строка вместо собственно нуля.

Comment: в пункте 4 поправьте  int_symbol(154 % 16) а не 9

Comment: @ARHovsepyan спасибо, поправил

Comment: @Qwertiy хммм, да, действительно. Получается единственный способ - сравнивать с основанием? Так не люблю, когда код дублируется... Окей, сейчас уберу это из ответа.

Comment: вот теперь можно отметить как полезный

Comment: @selya, можно не убирать, просто пометить, что это верно для положительных чисел. Вообще, у рекурсивных функций часто бывает некая предподготовка, т. е. вызывается другая функция, которая сначала что-то делает, а потом вызывает рекурсивную. В таком случае проверку на начальное нулевое значение можно поместить в неё, а рекурсивную функцию сделать в том варианте, как ты предложил. Ещё один способ избежать дублирования - проверять значение перед вызовом, а не внутри него: `void ten_base(int in, int base) { if (in>=base) { ten_base(in/base, base); } cout << int_symbol(in%base); }`. Как-то так :)

Comment: @Qwertiy да, про второй вариант сейчас сам подумал. А дополнительная функция - да, так часто сам делаю. Однако, это лишь усложнит все в данном случае, как мне кажется) Добавлю второй вариант вместо своего тогда